# Python send ACK very fast

Tags: python, ssl, tcp

I am trying to do TLS handshaking. My server side mbedTLS and client side python script.

I am using this source codes for the client :

https://github.com/arthurazs/python-tls/blob/master/client.py

In the image/wireshark at the line 12, after the Server send hello message, client send ACK message very fast so my Server side couldnt catch this frame. How can I send ACK again or give a some time space after getting Hello Server on python code ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> How can I send ACK again ...

They are already sent again. Since the server resends the ServerHello, the client sends the ACK for it. It is always the same ServerHello and always the same ACK. If the server cannot deal with this than there is something wrong in the server code.

> ...  or give a some time space after getting Hello Server on python code ?

This is not possible from user space code. The ACK is sent by the OS kernel immediately after the data were  received by the client OS. The application is not involved in sending the ACK nor can it defer it.